# create a day calculator that validates the inputs

Tags: python

```
def month_date_valid(month):
    if month > 0 and month <= 12: 
        return True
    else: 
        return false
def get_day_count(month, days):
    list1 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,11]
    list2 = [2,4,6,9,]
    count = 0 
    for i in range(1, month):
        if i in list1:
            count+31
        elif i in list2: 
            count+30 
    else: 
        count+= 28
    return count + days
    
list1 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,11]
list2 = [2,4,6,9,]
for i in range(1,13):
    if i in list1:
        for j in range(1, 30):
            answer = get_day_count(i,j)
            print((i, j), 'is', answer)
    elif i in list2:
        for j in range(1, 31): 
            answer = get_day_count(i, j)
            print((i, j), 'is', answer)
    else: 
        for j in range(1,29):
            answer = get_day_count(i, j)
            print((i, j), 'is', answer) 
def main():
    month = int(input('Enter the month of the year: '))
    day = int(input('Enter the day of the year: '))
    if month_date_valid(month):
        month = (get_day_count(month, day))
        return True 
    else: 
        print('Month in invalid, try again')
```

where did i go wrong because it's suppose ask me to enter the month and date and see if the month and day is valid? I'm really stuck and need help fast. any ideas welcome.

Comment: You defined a `main()` function but you never _called_ it.  Python does not automatically call `main()` for you, unlike some other languages (notably C).

Answer (score 0):

You defined a `main()` function but you never called it. Python does not automatically call `main()` for you, unlike some other languages.

- *credit to John Gordon for posting the answer in the comments*